# Name a cell based on an abbreviated sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, header, footer, naming

I have sheets with abbreviated names such as "LOL" or ROFL"

I need the macro i have to go through and type out the full phrase in the left header depending on what the sheet name is.

I know how to do that normally with *activesheet.name*, but i don't know how to write out the full name. i suspect it will need a case and a loop of some sort.

IE "LOL"--> Header name will be "Laugh out Loud"

"Rofl" --> Header name will be "Rolling on the floor laughing"

Thank you!

Comment: where you do have the abbreviated name mapped to the full name? Meaning your examples surely aren't *real world*.

Comment: Thats the thing, i don't have that. And i don't want a reference/guide sheet. I need the remapping to happen behind the scenes in the code if possible. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want a mapping sheet. Just a hidden tab that has the mapping? Otherwise, you can load mapping to a dictionary or array each time and then use that. EIther way you'll have to type the mapping up at least once.

Comment: Without some kind of mapping, how is Excel supposed to know that `LOL` does not mean `Lucy, Our Lady`

Comment: this is part of a larger macro/userform i have developed. My plan is to let others use it by saving it in thier personal macros. then we can load it into each workbook without having to load/ save as .xlsxm..a mapping sheet would complicate that. Is there no other way you know of? Perhaps do the mapping within the code itself?

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary. In some languages, another name for it happens to be a `Map`; it's *meant* for that.

Reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, and make a function whose sole responsibility is to deal with that:

```
Private Function GetFullName(ByVal shortName As String) As String
    Static values As Scripting.Dictionary
    If values Is Nothing Then
        Set values = New Scripting.Dictionary
        values.Add "LOL", "Laugh out Loud"
        values.Add "ROFL", "Rolling on the floor laughing"
        '...
    End If

    If values.Exists(shortName) Then
        GetFullName = values(shortName)
    Else
        'raise an error:
        'Err.Raise 5, "GetFullName", "Key '" & shortName & "' was not found."
        '...or otherwise handle the situation for a missing key.
    End If
End Function
```

The downside is that, well, you're mixing *data* with *code* here. Data doesn't *belong* in code. You could have a (hidden?) worksheet to hold a table with the mapping data instead, and populate the dictionary from that table. That way when the mappings need to change, your code doesn't.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reponse. I can't use a map/ref sheet even hidden bc i plan to distribute this to others in their personal macros. that way its usable in any open doc without extra work (For those who don't know anything about macros) I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible for those people. Thanks again!

Comment: How are you distributing it? As an Excel add-in (.xlam)? An Excel add-in *is* a workbook, and you can very well use its worksheets to store data. I'm sorry I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: my plan is an xlsb

Comment: I still don't see what the problem might be.

Comment: if a coworker has an excel file. isnt it easier to load a personal macro one time and have it be available every time. isnt your option adding in a hidden worksheet to every book that the macro is loaded into?

Comment: If the macro-book contains its own data, there is no problem is there? You don't add the data/worksheet to every book they ever open, just to the workbook you're distributing.

Comment: Also you should consider distributing it as an Excel add-in, so that your users don't even have to *think* to open your macro workbook - it's always loaded with Excel itself.

Comment: @mattrashty - Look at the "Microsoft Excel Objects" tree of your add-in.  You'll see (at very least) "ThisWorkbook" and "Sheet1".  Those objects don't magically disappear when you save it as an add-in. You can put as much data in there as you need to.

Comment: Once a user has added your code/data to their personal macros, how do you go about distributing bug fixes and enhancements? Use an add-in. You can load an add-in from a network share, so all users always get the latest copy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea how you could map sheet names using VBA code via *Case Statments*

```
Sub Example()   
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim OutputString As String
    OutputString = ""

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case WS.Name
            Case "ROFL"
                OutputString = "Rolling on floor laughing"
            Case "LOL"
                OutputString = "Laugh out loud"
        End Select

        'Do something
        If OutputString <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Output for desired name: " & OutputString
            OutputString = ""
        End If            
    Next WS   
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't the `If OutputString <> "" Then` condition backwards? I think I'd move that part in a `Case Else` block ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have adjusted my answer. Are you referring to something like this? I greatly appreciate the tip as I am learning each day myself.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I completely misread the intent! I thought the conditional block after the `Select Case`  was for handling the case where a match was *not* found! :S